# Programmatically force validation on Silverlight 3 UIElement (Textbox)

Tags: c#, validation, c#-4.0, silverlight-3.0, uielement

Is there an easy to to programmatically force a uielement to validate in Silverlight 3?

I have a textbox where i bind a `Silverlight.Validators.RegexValidator` to, unfortunately the validator checks against another uielements content (combobox). Normally onSelectionChanged on that combobox - its selected item is set in the validator, and when the textbox content changes (key presses), it checks against this.

But i also want to run the same validation again when the combobox selection changes

can i do something like `myTextBox.Validate();` or even something like `myTextBox.KeyUp()` to force validation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `TextBox.Text` property is bound to some property, you can force the binding to update the source, which should lead to validation.

```
var bindingExpression = textBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
bindingExpression.UpdateSource();
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are using [this toolkit](http://silverlightvalidator.codeplex.com/) rather than the built-in binding validation system. According to [ValidatorBase](http://silverlightvalidator.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Source/Silverlight.Validators/ValidatorBase.cs), it seems you should call `Validate(true)` on your validator object.

I would strongly suggest you try to move over to the [official Silverlight data validation support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278072%28v=vs.95%29.aspx#data_validation) which is much more robust than simply validating TextBox.Text on KeyUp. For regex validation you can apply a [RegularExpressionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to the property the TextBox binds to. Once binding validation is set up, **Ed Chapel**'s answer will work for you. It's also likely that Silverlight would automatically requery the validation and you wouldn't need to handle SelectionChanged at all.